# How transcribe remove number custom function Excel VBA function to Google Sheets Google Script (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, google-apps-script, number-formatting

I need to transcribe a VBA script to Javascript but i got stuck in the java part

The main meaning is to remove numbers from a text like "texthere 123456789"

My VBA code is:

```
Function RemoveNum(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Global = True
.Pattern = "[0-9]"
RemoveNum = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```

My Javascript attempt was:

```
function RemoveNumbers(RemoveNumbers) {
  var RemoveNumbers;
  //var str = RemoveNumbers.toString();
  var str = RemoveNumbers;
  str.Value.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
}
```

Or even:

```
function rn(remvnum) {
var str = remvnum;
var n = str.toString();
var res = n.replace(/[0-9]/gmi, '');

}
```

What does stop me reaching the result is, the .Replace function needs to be string content otherwise will return error of undefined value, also I can't  convert toString because it returns error of undefined value.

This example bellow works well as the name of the function is written in the Google Sheet cell as a custom function, but I didn't achieve the remove number desire:

```
function styleHyphenFormat(propertyName) {
  function upperToHyphenLower(match, offset, string) {
    return (offset ? '-' : '') + match.toLowerCase();
  }
  return propertyName.replace(/[A-Z]/g, upperToHyphenLower);
}
```

Does someone knows what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `removeNumbers = removeNumbers.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');` or set a new var like `noNums = removeNumbers.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');`

Comment: I did like bellow, with no luck:

`function rn(){`
`var rn`
`var noNums = rn.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `return` the replaced value:

```
function rn(remvnum) {
 //var str = remvnum;
 //var n = str.toString();
 var res = remvnum.toString().replace(/[0-9]/gmi, '');
 return res; //Added
}
```

Google sheets supports regex([re2](/questions/tagged/re2)) as a built-in function unlike excel. So, You don't need macros. Even if you want a global replace, The Find and replace menu works well with regex.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\d",)
```

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A5,"\d",))
```

- `\d` is `d`igit(==`[0-9]`)

Comment: I did your code but Google Scripts still saying that he "can't call the method 'toString' as undefined, maybe Google Scripts is missing something from the Java API?

In the other hand the native Google formula "=REGEXREPLACE" did the job for me, so far so good.

Thank you!

Comment: @VChaves You need to call the function from cell `=rn(A2)`

Comment: Yes I did, the result in the custom formula was a blank cell doe to the Java error